# how to get ios devices' information nearby with Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, bluetooth

How could I set the ios devices' (iphone & ipad) bluetooth visible for other ios devices when turn the bluetooth on?
I just want to get and show all the ios devices' name (MFI devices include) nearby in my app when all devices' bluetooth on, and I also want to get devices' deviceID.
I have succed using GameKit.framework to connect two ios devices by using bluetooth, but this requires the two devices run that app together.
Could some one provide me suggest on how to implement it? Thank you very much!

Comment: gamekit framework bluetooth!please google

Answer (score 1):

i my self have not worked on it, i know its not good to give link here.But hope these links will get u to start on your-self:
  http://www.touchthatfruit.com/ios-bluetooth-development-tutorial-using-game

http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

happy to help

Comment: Thank you!I have worked some time with private API, but didn't implement it and gave it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Setting a device's bluetooth on is not enough. A device needs to be advertising for peers to detected it. I think this might be related to what you are trying to do: http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/.

I tried this tutorial and it was very helpful. It uses Multipeer Connectivity to advertise and browse for peers around. It also displays the deviceID of devices around you.